# How can I create a PFX file from a Java Keystore?

Tags: java, .net, certificate, pfx, jks

I have a Java keystore (.jks file) holding a single certificate. How can I create a .pfx file from this keystore?

Answer (score 72):

From Java 6 onwards, `keytool` has an `-importkeystore` option, which should be able to convert a JKS store into a PKCS#12 store (.p12/.pfx):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore thekeystore.jks \
            -srcstoretype JKS \
            -destkeystore thekeystore.pfx \
            -deststoretype PKCS12
```

It will ask you to enter a password for source and destination (jks, pfx) files

Comment: I am getting these errors when I use this command: Problem importing entry for alias root: java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported.  Have you seen that?

Comment: @mikebz Yes, you can't have entries with only certificates in the PKCS#12 store, it only works for entries for which there is also a private key.

Answer (score 3):

This guy() seems to have written a little Java class and batch file with good instructions to do this here: http://www.crionics.com/products/opensource/faq/signFree.htm#DownloadTools

If you want to do it yourself the key lines in the .bat file seem to be uses

```
keytool -export -rfc -keystore %KEYSTORE% -storepass %PASSWORD% -alias %ALIAS% > %CERT_64%
java -classpath %JAVACLASSPATH% ExportPrvKey %KEYSTORE% %PASSWORD% %ALIAS% > %PKEY_8%
openssl enc -in %PKEY_8% -a >> %PKEY_64%
openssl pkcs12 -inkey %PKEY_64% -in %CERT_64% -out %CERT_P12% -export
```

where ExportPrvKey does the step of extracting the private key from the keystore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also came across the site you linked via Google and tried it out. However, the last step fails for me. openssl terminates with the message:

unable to load private key

Any additional hints would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the private key file (%PKEY_64%). Does it actually exist? Googling it seems the most common errors are having it in the wrong directory or a bad format. Which version of openssl do you have?

Comment: The PKEY_64 file exists and looks ok (it contains 858 "random" ascii characters). I'm using openssl 0.9.7d on a linux box.

Answer (score 1):

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore [MY_KEYSTORE.jks] -destkeystore [MY_FILE.p12] -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12`

Then it will request your passphrases and BAM - good to go, tried just last night worked great.

you may have to change dir to your java jdk, or jre bin folder first, then include a full path to your current Keystore, and dest .p12 file.

Answer (score -1):

You can export a PFX file including private key, with the following command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass secret -destkeypass secret -destkeystore KEYSTOREFILE.jks -srckeystore PFXFILE.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass secret
```